# how do i setup nginx websites as in Xampp

Tags: php, yii, nginx

I am trying to migrate from XAMPP to Nginx webserver. I used to have multiple websites running  with Xampp with each web folder residing under xampp/htdocs folder. so for example, I will access sites(yii web sites) as [code]http://myserver/site1[code] and [code]http://myserver/site2[code] and they would be accessed from the site1 and site2 folders under htdocs. But I am having trouble setting this up in nginx. I have setup the default configuration with the root folder as /etc/share/nginx/www  (and site1 and site2 folders are under www) and when i access the same way with nginx, the webpage gives an error saying "No Input file specified". I understand that  multiple sites are setup in nginx with different domain names and different root folders, but is it possible to have the xampp like configuration? Because i am testing this on my local network and i do not want to setup multiple domain names for this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be XNmpp then?

Comment: note:there is an alternative xampp/wampp with nginx: https://wtserver.wtriple.com

Answer (score 2):

Config for latest nginx versions is pretty simple. First you should edit `nginx/conf/nginx.conf` and make sure you have something like `include vhosts/*.conf;` inside `http {` section. That will make nginx look for extra configs under `vhosts`.

Also it's a good idea to declare the following in `http {` as well not to repeat it for each individual config:

```
gzip  on;
charset utf-8;
index index.php index.htm index.html;
```

Then in `nginx/conf/vhosts/mydomain.com.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    root    /var/www/mydomain.com/www;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # Redirect everything that isn't real file to index.php including arguments.
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf; # that's if you have one of latest versions of nginx. If not, see below
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000; # or pass through socket if it's how you've configured php-fpm
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

In case you don't have `fastcgi.conf` here it is:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Now the only thing left is to add `mydomain.com` to your hosts file so it's recognized locally.

Answer (score 1):

That's simple.

Drop your databases, compress them, import them again OR use mysql -u root -p BASENAME < /the/path/BASEDROP.sql

Then simply move your default dir like /var/www/html and set permissions to 0777 or less by using chmod 0777 -R /the/path and also use chown www-data:www-data -R /the/path AND THEN reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after struggling through I finally found the ideal configuration. I understand this is not a recommended setup, but this is the give problem for me (nginx with multiple sites as subdirectories) and had to find a solution for it.

```
location /Site1/ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www/Site1;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # the images need a seperate entry as we dont want to concatenate that with index.php      
    location ~ /Site1/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www/Site1;
    }
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ /Site1/.+\.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #       # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
location /Site3/ {
            root    /usr/share/nginx/www/Site3;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ /Site3/.+\.php$ {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            #we are directly using the $request_filename as its a single php script
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
```

More details on this blog, http://programmersjunk.blogspot.com/2013/11/nginx-multiple-sites-in-subdirectories.html